# Custom field calculation on a pivot table using external data or range in other sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

Hi i want to create a custom calculated field in a pivot table.

I have a table on **Sheet2** named **tblPerson**.

And my datasource for my Pivot Table is in **Sheet1**

Like this:
[image: Pivot_Table]

and my table: [image: tblPerson]

I want to use the data from tblPerson on my Pivot Table, like this:
[image: dialoguebox]

Does any one knows how to link that information or how to use it on my Pivot Table???

> Note: I know that this question is similar to this [Question](http://goo.gl/PnQhls),  but in this case i want to link a table.

Comment: I think your usage of formulas for a calculated field is severely limited.  IIRC, you can maybe use `SUM` but that's about it beyond basic math operators.  I'll see if I can find a reference...

Comment: See http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html in the `limitations` section near the top.  Not sure if that info is verified anywhere else, but I have encountered that page while searching after trying to do something similar.